# Closing gaps in objects of opencv mask

Tags: c++, opencv

I've computed the following mask of an image containing corn:
[image]

the problem is, now i have black parts inside the seeds. Is there a way to get rid of them while making sure that seeds remain disconnected from each other?

---

My ultimate goal is to count the seeds on the picture, using watershed algorithm. I observed when the seeds are touching each other, it introduces a imprecision to the algorithm, so I tried to introduce gaps between seeds by using canny and subtracting the borders from the mask, which is the result above.

My code so far:

```
auto img = GetAreaOfInterest(orig, bt); // <- just a Gauss blur with OTSU thresh
{
    cv::Mat gray, edges;
    cv::cvtColor(orig, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    // tried bilateralFIlter here, but things only got worse

    cv::Canny(gray, edges, 40, 160);
    cv::dilate(edges, edges,
               cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, {5, 5}),
               {-1, -1}, 1);

    img.setTo(0, edges != 0); 
}

cv::Mat background, foreground, unknown, markers;
cv::dilate(img, background,
           cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, {3,3}));

/* Get area for which we are sure it's the foreground */
cv::distanceTransform(img, img, cv::DIST_L1, 3, CV_8U);
{
    double max;
    cv::minMaxLoc(img, nullptr, &max);
    cv::threshold(img, img, 0.46 * max, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

}
img.convertTo(foreground, CV_8UC3);
show_resized("distance", foreground, 0.5);

/* Mark unknown areas */
cv::subtract(background, foreground, unknown);

/* Set up markers */
cv::connectedComponents(foreground, markers);
markers = markers + 1;
markers.setTo(0, unknown == 255);

/* Expand markers */
cv::watershed(orig, markers);

// Count objects
```

original image:
[image]

the most problematic image:
[image]

Comment: Why not use erosion to seperate the seeds initially?

Comment: @DrBwts tried erosion as well, but it didn't work.

Comment: the worse the resolution, the worse the problem gets. traditional methods have limits. -- for automated optical inspection/machine vision, you'd control the environment (separate the corns physically) rather than look for magic solutions. -- you could always throw AI at it. instance segmentation.